# TldLocationsCache: null - Importing taglib on tomcat6

Tags: java, tomcat, tags, tomcat6, taglib

I am getting the infamous TldLocationsCache: null. :-(

My taglib is inside the META-INF of my jar. So in my web.xml I do:

```
<jsp-config> 
   <taglib> 
      <taglib-uri>myTags</taglib-uri> 
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/myTagLib-2.0.0.jar</taglib-location> 
   </taglib> 
</jsp-config>
```

And on my JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="myTags" prefix="m" %>
```

But then I get:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to initialize TldLocationsCache: null
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.init(TldLocationsCache.java:248)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.getLocation(TldLocationsCache.java:219)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getTldLocation(JspCompilationContext.java:553)
```

I am running Tomcat6. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<taglib-location>` should refer to the `.tld`, so change

```
<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/myTagLib-2.0.0.jar</taglib-location>
```

to

```
<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/myTagLib-2.0.0.tld</taglib-location>
```

or something similar with the path of the `tld` file.

This could be also useful: [Removing <taglib> from web.xml](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/RemovingTaglibFromWeb.xml)